# Angular bootstrap conditionally-required fields

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

This seems to be very common, yet the solutions for it seem complex.

I've got a section of my form that is optional. If enabled, then its fields are required.

```
<!-- begin optional section -->
<label>
    <h4>Trailer </h4> 
    <span>( optional </span>
    <input class="input-inline" ng-model="hasTrailer" type="checkbox"/> 
    <span>)</span> 
    <h4 style="display: inline"> :</h4>
</label> 


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="trailerNumber"> Number:</label>
    <div>
        <input 
         type="text" 
         name="trailerNumber" 
         ng-disabled="!hasTrailer" 
         ng-model="vm.Manifest.Trailer.number" 
         required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div 
             class="error-message" 
             ng-show="hasTrailer && form.trailerNumber.$invalid && form.trailerNumber.$touched || form.submitted">
            <span> Trailer Number is required.</span >
        </div>
    </div>             
</div>
<!-- end optional section -->
```

So, at the top of the section there is a checkbox, whose model is 'trailer'.
If checked, the fields are required.

What I really want is ideally:

```
<input type="text" required="hasTrailer">
```

or maybe

```
<input type="text" ng-attr({'required':hasTrailer})
```

i.e. if hasTrailer===true then required=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ng-required` directive which will conditionally make input `required` when provided expression becomes true.

```
<input type="text" ng-required="hasTrailer">
```

Comment: Oops. *You* beat *him*! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using ngRequired. You can read about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired)

It is basically used like this in the html element

```
<input type="text" ng-required="hasTrailer">
```

**hasTrailer** should be a boolean property in the scope.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Glad I asked, or I would have assumed those more complex solutions were the only way ...

Answer (score 0):

I was about to go with this option, which does the same thing, but additionally makes the whole section disappear.

```
<div ng-if="hasTrailer">
    <!-- all my optional fields-->
</div>
```